# jQuery.getScript does not work with jQuery Version 3.x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reloading/re-executing my javascript using jquery's getScript  function with

```
 jQuery('#my-script').empty();
  jQuery.getScript( 'js/myscript.js', function() { 
  });
```

This worked fine with jquery V1.x or V2.x. Since jquery v3.x the reload works but the re-execute of script fails with error

```
uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let varname
```

where "varname" is a class like

```
class varname {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }  
  method1 { .. }  
  }
```

I think the problem is caused by the ES6 Javascript standard. But I could not find a solution to fix my problem other than use the older jquery versions. Has anybody a clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem - it is caused by ES6 standard,
which changes the process of scoping of variables. I had to define my classes as:

```
var varname = class varname {...}
```

This solved the issue. Just defining

```
class varname {...}
```

will result in a definition of.

```
let varname = class varname {...}
```

and this wil cause a failed redeclaration.